# C++ for loop no output in other way

Tags: c++, for-loop

I've been writting some codes for my practise and now I have a trouble.
I need to find divisors of inputted number and output them in file.
Example:
Input: 30
Output: 1 2 3 5 6 10 15 30
This is working pretty well, but answers are like: 30 15 10 6 5 3 2 1 (from other side, but I need from 1 to ...)

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sk; // number
    ifstream fd ("input.txt");
    ofstream fr ("output.txt");
    fd >> sk;
    for (int i = 1; i < sk++; i++){
        if (sk % i == 0) fr << sk/i << " ";
    }
    fd.close ();
    fr.close ();
}
```

I've tryed this, but not working, what's the problem?

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sk; // number
    ifstream fd ("input.txt");
    ofstream fr ("output.txt");
    fd >> sk;
    for (int i = sk; i < 0; i--){
        if (sk % i == 0) fr << sk/i << " ";
    }
    fd.close ();
    fr.close ();
}
```

Comment: Do you expect "i < 0" to ever be true in your for loop?

Comment: "It's not working"?????

Comment: Now it is, with this loop:    for (int i = sk; i > 1; i--){
            if (sk % i == 0) fr << sk/i << " ";
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop has the wrong condition:

```
  for (int i = sk; i < 0; i--){
        if (sk % i == 0) fr << sk/i << " ";
    }
```

With the condition i<0 it never enters the loop. It should be:

```
for (int i = sk; i >0 0; i--){
        if (sk % i == 0) fr << sk/i << " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of outputting `sk/i`, output just `i`.

Your i is increasing in ascending order. But you are outputting its counterpart factor 1st. Hence it is getting outputted in decreasing order.

Also, in your second loop, change your termination condition to i >= 1:

```
for (int i = sk; i >= 1; i--){
```

Comment: If I would output only i, I'd get 30 15 10 6 5 3 2 1 again, so if output i, I need to use this     
    for (int i = 1; i < sk++; i++)

Comment: @MementoMori Yes, if you output i, then i should be increasing from 1, and if you output sk/i, then it should be decreasing from sk.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output from 1 to sk, the for loop has to look like here:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sk; // number
    ifstream fd ("input.txt");
    ofstream fr ("output.txt");

    fd >> sk;
    for (int i = 1; i <= sk; i++)
        if (sk % i == 0) fr << i << " ";

    fd.close ();
    fr.close ();
}
```

This will output 1 2 3 5 6 10 15 30